# Dry Joint and Connection?

Tags: soldering

I have a PCB with through the hole components on it and its temperamental does this mean that I have a dry joint? As I plug something in to the board and its stops being recognised on the computer(the programming software that is)? I have molex connectors to join every thing together. But these connections don't seem very good. I have read the voltage at my supply and at the pin of the pic and they are the same. So I assumed that this connection is "good". Some of the joints on my PCB aren't volcano like more balls on the copper tracks. Could this be causing the problem? I don't have a good enough camera to get pictures of my soldering.

Comment: Not enough information!

Comment: Edited if you need to know anything else i will add.

Comment: Your steps to reproduce are "plug something into the board" and the result is "it stops being recognized by the programming software".  There is an enormous number of potential sources for this problem - Software, hardware, cables, power supply, solder connections, PCB traces...the list goes on, and on, and on.

Comment: Copyright law prevents me from posting the entire text of *[Debugging: The 9 Indispensable Rules for Finding Even the Most Elusive Software and Hardware Problems* by David Agans](http://www.amazon.com/Debugging-David-J-Agans/dp/0814474578/) as an answer, but I'll recommend it.

Comment: That looks an awsome book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the note of your ball joints, yes, often a really bad joint can show up as a "ball" of solder, instead of the volcano shape.

The second note here, when you measure voltage at your pic and at the source, the only sort of verifies one line. The connection could be very resistive or just having temporary contact. I have seen people probe pins and when they place pressure on the pin it causes a contact that was not there, the board works as long as you measure it.

Lead free solder requires a higher temp to get a good joint on, probably the root of the problem to begin with. Also, just because power makes it, your ground may not, or your crystal may not be properly connected, clean up those bad joints!

Start debugging again once you have them clean. Make sure to use your multimeter for connectivity check but make sure to look at what resistance it is measuring.

Answer (score 2):

'dry' joints have a characteristic sheen (not nice and silvery) - more likely you just have something loose (a non-joint)

Fixing this stuff is easy just touch them up with a soldering iron, don;t just let the solder flow make sure the component leads get hot enough to melt solder on their own

Comment: This is true, unless you're using lead-free solder ... all joints good and bad tend to look dull with it, making visual inspection much more difficult.

Comment: Yeah i'm using lead free solder. :/

Answer (score 2):

Try resoldering the suspect joints with a solder with a more active flux, or add some active liquid or jelly flux to the joints. Ensure that you are using the correct soldering temperature and the bit is the correct size, and properly tinned.